# gluPickMatrix - something's wrong and an object is always on the scene

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics, 3d

I have the following code to draw an openGL scene

```
void QGLDiagramWidget::paintGL()
{

    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    ... load shaders...

    ... load buffers...

    ... load textures...

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set viewport area
    glViewport(0, 0, this->size().width(), this->size().height());

    GLint view[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, view);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPickMatrix(1, 1, 1, 1, view); // THIS IS THE RELEVANT CODE

    // I don't use a fixed pipeline, so let's store this pickmatrix in a variable
    Matrix pickingPerspMatrix;
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, pickingPerspMatrix); // This is successful in my code

    // Create the projection matrix
    gl_projection.setToIdentity();
    gl_projection *= pickingPerspMatrix; // APPLY THE PICKING MATRIX
    gl_projection.perspective(45.,((GLfloat)this->size().width())/((GLfloat)this->size().height()),0.1f,100.0f);



    ... now draw the entire scene with shaders, there's a camera matrix (view) and a model matrix (model) ...
}
```

As long as I know, this should take a pick matrix from the rect from bottom-left pixel 1,1 (the first of the scene) with width 1 and height 1 and multiply it by the identity matrix and then apply the perspective matrix over it.

The goal is: centering just my pixel area on the viewport and render whatever is really visible there.

Turns out that whatever value I put into the gluPickMatrix, the object in my viewport is ALWAYS visible, just shrinked or distorted or deformed, but always int he viewport area. And this is wrong since asking for the pick matrix from point (0;0) plus width 1 and height 1 should return an empty area.

This is the image that I obtain to help you understand the problem

[image]

Why is this happening? What is a pick matrix supposed to do? Translate the objects out of the scene? Since I use programmable pipelines in my shaders (they're basically simple shaders to load a texture on the object and use phong lighting), what could cause that object deformation and its constant presence on the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pickmatrix is used to restrict rendering to a small part of the viewport.  Read about gluPickMatrix here: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPickMatrix.xml

Picking won't work with your programmable pipeline. Picking works by associating each drawcall with a "name" (a number that represents the pickable object) and when rendering the scene with picking, it return any pixels/fragments.

The details are explained here: 
http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Picking
and here
web.engr.oregonstate.edu/.../Picking/picking.pdf

You might be better off avoiding deprecated functionality and use color picking, render each object with a unique solid color, then use glReadPixels to find out whats under the mouse.

Colorpicking is well explained here: http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL_Selection_Using_Unique_Color_IDs

Another possibility is using ray-primitive tests for selection.

Comment: Thank you, so color picking is a non-deprecated technique? It's not that easy for me to recognize a deprecated functionality since I'm an openGL newbie

Comment: Colorpicking isn't dependant on any feature of OpenGL. Its possible in any grahics api that allows you to draw 3D objects and read the resulting framebuffer. If you're want to know if a function or feature is deprecated, then it won't be in the GL 3 or 4 reference. Here's the 4.2 reference: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/

Comment: You could ask Qt for a GL 3.1 (or newer) profile, it will report errors if you try to use deprecated functionality. How this works in Qt: http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_use_OpenGL_Core_Profile_with_Qt